# How can I download, then delete a file on my website with PHP?

Tags: php, html, download, delete-file

I generate a *.csv file with PHP and it works great. The problem is, it contains a bunch of sensitive data. I've done my permissions very carefully, so you can't get to the download link or generate the file without being the correct user.
The issue that I run into, is that right after the user downloads the file, the file needs to be deleted right away. The chance is small, I realize, that someone would be sitting there scanning my site structure, but the data is important enough to where I want to cover my ass :-)

I had this at first:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_path().$ourFileName ?>"><?=$ourFileName?></a>
```

Which works great to just download the file, but I was having a hard time doing any kind of actions with it, because if you nest PHP code inside an OnClick="" it will be executed before the click happens, because all PHP code is rendered server-side before the HTML and JAVASCRIPT is processed...right? I searched the internet, and it didn't seem like I could get javascript to have the perms to delete the file...admittedly, I could be very wrong.

So I turned my link into a form:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    header("Location: ".base_path().$ourFileName);
    unlink(base_path().$ourFileName);
}?>

<form action="<? $PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

But obviously, the unlink() will never be reachable because of the header...at least I think...
Is there another way besides header() to download the file to them?
I realize I could just run a cron job every minute or something and just:

```
rm -rf *.csv
```

And that would take care of the issue, but what happens if a user is in the process of downloading the file and cron starts to run? Or the page is generated, but they don't click on the link for a while for some reason?

Maybe there's some way to configure my .htaccess file so you can only access the file if linking from a page?

Am I over complicating this?

Any ideas gurus of the interweb?

--edit
Per popular suggestion, I'm working on the new header format so the code looks like this:

```
<?PHP if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($user->uid))
{
    myroom_render_csv($ourFileName, $csv_string);
}?>

<form action="<? $PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and in a separate file:

```
<?PHP function myroom_render_csv($file_name, $csv_string) {
header('Content-type: text/csv');
$header_string2="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"";
header($header_string2);
echo $csv_string;
} ?>
```

but I get a dump of the full HTML page AND the CSV data. Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simpler solution - don't create a file.  Instead of writing your data to a .csv file, just set the headers in a php script like so:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="whatever.csv"');

echo $csv_data;
```

Print out your csv data in the php script, and the browser will treat it like a file download.  This way, you're free to control to who and when the file is accessible.

Comment: Note that `text/csv` doesn't universally behave the way you'd expect. I can't actually remember offhand which way round it was, but ISTR for example either FF or IE acting in some unexpected way unless the CSV data were presented as `text/plain`. Or possibly `application/csv`. Have a play around to see what works best for you in multiple browsers.

Comment: Dumping a full variable can be problematic if there's an absurd amount of data (increasing memory limits for just a single script is a bad idea if you ask me) 

A better approach is writing to `php://out` and also with php 5.1+ you have [fputcsv](http://es.php.net/fputcsv) which does most of the work for you

Comment: I've been trying to implement your function idea, and I know I must just be doing something dumb, because I can't get it.
I get the CSV data out fine, and it's formatted pretty much correctly, but I also get the full dump of the HTML page too.
How should this be called?

Comment: @rmontagud I was using fputcsv, put the issue was that we don't want to create a physical file that will exist on the server because it's just too insecure. Is there a way of hijacking fputcsv so that it will work with this header method?

Comment: @chrisbster This is a snippet of the code i'm using myself for that, i've stripped a lot of code related to my program and left the essential instructions https://gist.github.com/1074382

Comment: @rmontagud - I wasn't necessarily advocating that he put all his data in a variable; I was just attempting to give a general example of usage.

Comment: @rmontagud I was using something similiar. The issue that I keep running into isn't the csv generation itself now. I've got that down. The issue is that I'm inside Drupal and using a bunch of built in variables and functions, so I can't create an external *.php file. I'm getting the csv file downloaded, but it contains all the drupal header and footer information. i can't find a way of cleanly encapsulating it.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments.

---

> Which works great to just download the file,
>   but I was having a hard time doing any
>   kind of actions with it, because if
>   you nest PHP code inside an OnClick=""
>   it will be executed before the click
>   happens, because all PHP code is
>   rendered server-side before the HTML
>   and JAVASCRIPT is processed...right? I
>   searched the internet, and it didn't
>   seem like I could get javascript to
>   have the perms to delete the
>   file...admittedly, I could be very
>   wrong.

You're absolutely correct.

---

> I generate a *.csv file with PHP and
>   it works great. The problem is, it
>   contains a bunch of sensitive data.
>   I've done my permissions very
>   carefully, so you can't get to the
>   download link or generate the file
>   without being the correct user. The
>   issue that I run into, is that right
>   after the user downloads the file, the
>   file needs to be deleted right away.
>   The chance is small, I realize, that
>   someone would be sitting there
>   scanning my site structure, but the
>   data is important enough to where I
>   want to cover my ass :-)

Then why is it a file? Just send it to the browser with the relevant headers to hint the browser to present it to the user as a saveable file resource. It doesn't have to be a physical file on the webserver for this.

Others have provided the code for this; I really just wanted to point out that you were correct about the client-side/server-side angle. :)

---

> But obviously, the unlink() will never be reachable because of the header

Actually, no. `header` does not stop the script.

```
header("Location: ".base_path().$ourFileName);
unlink(base_path().$ourFileName);
```

Your `unlink` will have executed and finished long before the browser has gotten around to even *starting* the request for `base_path().$ourFileName`.

Usually, though, you should write `exit` to stop code processing after `header`:

```
header("Location: ".base_path().$ourFileName);
exit;
unlink(base_path().$ourFileName);
```

And now, as you say, yes, the `unlink` never occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't even think about using headers, because I've never done it before, but...very nice...that seems MUCH more secure than my idea. I'll start Googling on header-file shenanigans, if you've got a resource that you would recommend though, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @chrisbster: You want a resource? Look at Sam's answer. :)

Comment: Yeah I just saw that. :-)
Thanks internet!